# Blog template PHP

Tags: templates, blog

Here's the WP wordpress website: http://www.joaoalexandre.com/wordpressteste/

And here's the Blog section: http://www.joaoalexandre.com/wordpressteste/artigos/

How can I show a regular simple blog with posts and maybe categories and get rid of the extra garbage it currently has (slider, "Services" etc)?

I suppose the answer lies in creating a new template for this "Artigos" page (which is the blog)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be what your looking for: `

```
            <div class="blog-post">

                <?php static $count = 0; if ($count == "4") { break; } else { ?>                

                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                <ul class="meta">
                    <li><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></li>
                    <li>| </li>
                    <li><span>Posted By</span> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></li>
                    <li>| </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><?php comments_number('No comments yet','1 comment','% comments')?></a></li>
                </ul><!--end of meta-->

                <p>
                    <?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 350);?>
                    ...&nbsp;<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="readMore">Read More.</a>
                </p><!-- Display a maximum of 350 characters from the blog post -->                                             

                <?php $count ; } ?>                                   

            </div><!--end of blog-post-->

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>     

            <?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) {
                wp_paginate();
            } ?> `
```

very simple to pull 4 blog posts per page limited by characters (350). Just make sure in Wordpress Reading settings you have a set home page and a set blog page.

Comment: is that put into the template the Page is assigned to? 

I did just that. I assigned the Page "Artigos" to a fullwidthblog.php template with that code in it, but it's still the same.

Btw I have removed the slider finally.

Comment: Nope that should be put in to index.php file.

Comment: Gives me an error when I put it there.

I would put the code in but I can't format it in these comments.

Comment: Here is an example of my entire index.php file: http://pastebin.com/F9khFceg

Comment: This is my index.php: http://pastebin.com/Ybb3fnyR

Comment: Oh, we posted at the same time more or less.

I tried your index.php file, didn't work. But I have posted my index.php above.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDWHILE in /home/joao/public_html/wordpressteste/wp-content/themes/main-files/revival/index.php on line 1  >>>>>>>> this is the error it gives me. Starts right on line 1? Is my index.php I posted above near yours any clue?

Comment: Not sure what is in your welcome.php file. But this should work by just dropping the code in if you made a blank Blog page, with no content in the WP dashboard, and in the WP settings you set a specific home page and specific blog page (the blank one you designated under pages).

Comment: Do you think it's the welcome.phP? Here's the welcome: http://pastebin.com/z9TmP4YN |||||||||||| By the way I have a specific page assigned as homepage and a specific blog page assigned as well (It's the Artigos page).

Comment: Well I don't see the PHP that I provided anywhere in your index.php file or the welcome.php. I would delete welcome.php fist. Then wherever you want the blog posts to show up put the PHP I originally put in here (first post)

Answer (score 0):

You dont mentioned clearly about your blog section.
If [artigos](http://www.joaoalexandre.com/wordpressteste/artigos/) is a page, you can use a page template. Hope [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) will be useful to you to create a page template.

If your blog section is a category then you should create a [category template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates).

Comment: Lakshmanan, I can create a page template for it (and choose the template when creating/editing the page), I just don't know what to put in the page template to make it work as a simple blog without the extra fillings it has currently.

how could I do that?